# mantis custom status only changing new status when set?

Tags: mantis

so I followed the tutorial here
https://www.mantisbt.org/docs/master/en-US/Admin_Guide/html/admin.customize.status.html
In my config_inc.php I have

```
$g_status_enum_string = '10:reported,20:development_pending,30:development_in_progress,40:qa_pending,50:qa_in_progress,60:return_to_development,70:qa_completed,80:deployed_to_production,90:closed';
```

and in
custom_constants_inc.php I have

```
define( 'REPORTED', 10 );
define( 'DEVELOPMENT_PENDING', 20 );
define( 'DEVELOPMENT_IN_PROGRESS', 30 );
define( 'QA_PENDING', 40 );
define( 'QA_IN_PROGRESS', 50 );
define( 'RETURN_TO_DEVELOPMENT', 60 );
define( 'QA_COMPLETED', 70 );
define( 'DEPLOYED_TO_PRODUCTION', 80 );
define( 'CLOSED', 90 );
```

When I load it a ticket I only see that "return_to_development" and "qa_completed" have changed, the rest of the string are still the old ones. And those 2 are the only NEW status codes, so I am not sure how to make the system recognize that I changed the original status codes?
Also in the workflow transitions page the new ones are listed as "@60@   @70@ " and the rest still have the old names. Its like its not picking up custom_constants_inc.php?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ok I figured it out. I missed that I needed to define "$s_status_enum_string = ..." in the custom_strings_inc.php